# How do you find out which version of mono is installed on a CentOS machine?

Tags: centos, centos-5, mono-framework

How do you find out which version of mono is installed on a CentOS machine? (N00b alert - what's the command prompt/shell command to find the version number of mono?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mono ships with a number of command line tools including the compiler (mcs), the interpreter (mint), and of course `mono` to name the main tools. Assuming you mean `mono` itself, simply run:

```
mono -V
```

or

```
mono --version
```

Comment: This outputs the version of the Mono JIT compiler.  Any way to figure out which version of .NET is installed also?

Comment: How do I take this output and parse it in Bash? I just want to check if it's >= a specific version.